# ASP Hyperlink not found in Site.master.cs?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, hyperlink

I have this code in my `Site.master` :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %> 
<!-- ... -->
<AnonymousTemplate>
    [ <asp:HyperLink ID="LoginHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Log In</asp:HyperLink> | 
    <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> ]
</AnonymousTemplate>
```

I have this code in my `Site.master.cs` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
// ...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is just placeholder for now. 
    RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
}
```

I'm getting a **Compile-Time** error in `Visual Studio 2010` at the `RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl` saying :

> "The name 'RegisterHyperLink' does not exist in the current context."

Not really sure what's up. I've seen this work in non-Master pages, so does this just not work in Masters?

I'd think it would...

Comment: It could be that the `AnonymousTemplate` is not active. Are you logged in?

Comment: See above edit. This won't compile.

Comment: Any chance you could post the relevant parts of both files?

Comment: @TomasVoracek - It is an ASP.NET property that only shows up if the user is not signed in (aka anonymous).

Comment: Is AnonymousTemplate just in markup or does it have all required things like InstantiateIn method etc? I think that you can use it for controls only, not pages/masterpages.

Comment: I have moved on from this question, and have voted to close it. If I ever come back to this and figure it out, I will post my results.

Answer (score 3):

It´s a bug, add a new HyperLink in Desing/Source save and try again. Delete the new hyperlink to finish

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure that your code-behind is inheriting from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`.
- Ensure the aspx has the appropriate directive added and that it is spelt right with correct case:

  `<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>`

Comment: Both those things are there, and it still does not work. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, `System.Web.UI.MasterPage` does not seem to exist.

Comment: @kevlar1818 - That may be the problem, this is an ASP.NET solution rather than just a Web Site?  Try and create a new master page by right clicking and selecting MasterPage. If you get one try to compare with the problem masterpage to see if there are any differences.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this AnonymousTemplate. It probably creates new naming container thus is not directly accessible from Page_Load.

Comment: However this works fine, as I have above, if it is not a master page.